# Is there any way to reduce time complexity to find this matrix to the power n?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on a problem where I am supposed to find `nth` power of a `4x4` matrix where `n` can be as large as `10^15` and since values in answer can be very large I can use `modulo 10^9+7` .
Given Matrix is-

```
   2  1 -2 -1
A= 1  0  0  0
   0  1  0  0
   0  0  1  0
```

I have written a code for this purpose but its running time is more than desired time. So 
anyone please help me in reducing time complexity.

```
#define FOR(k,a,b) for(typeof(a) k=(a); k < (b); ++k)
typedef long long ll;
#define dim 4
struct matrix {
    long long a[dim][dim];
};
#define MOD 1000000007
matrix mul(matrix x, matrix y)
{
    matrix res;
    FOR(a, 0, dim) FOR(b, 0, dim) res.a[a][b] = 0;
    FOR(a, 0, dim) FOR(b, 0, dim) FOR(c, 0, dim) {
    ll temp = x.a[a][b] * y.a[b][c];
    if (temp <= -MOD || temp >= MOD)
        temp %= MOD;
    res.a[a][c] += temp;
    if (res.a[a][c] <= -MOD || res.a[a][c] >= MOD)
        res.a[a][c] %= MOD;
    }
    return res;
}

matrix power(matrix m, ll n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return m;
    matrix u = mul(m, m);
    u = power(u, n / 2);
    if (n & 1)
        u = mul(u, m);
    return u;
}

matrix M, RP;
int main()
{
    FOR(a, 0, dim) FOR(b, 0, dim) M.a[a][b] = 0;
    M.a[0][0] = 2;
    M.a[0][1] = 1;
    M.a[0][2] = -2;
    M.a[0][3] = -1;
    M.a[1][0] = 1;
    M.a[2][1] = 1;
    M.a[3][2] = 1;
    int nt;
    scanf("%d", &nt);
    while (nt--) {
    ll n;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    RP = power(M, n);
    FOR(a, 0, dim)
        FOR(b, 0, dim)
        printf("%lld\n", RP.a[a][b]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix-exponentiation_operator#C.2B.2B could give you some ideas.

Comment: I have indented your code for readability. Please remember about that next time, it helps answering your questions.

Comment: @liori thank you. I'll keep than in mind next time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the timing demands? That code isn't too bad, it should be fast enough for most purposes.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am using this code for at most `10^4` test cases i.e `nt` in main function can go upto `10^4` and `n<=10^15` and time constraint is 2 seconds. For worst case when `nt=10^4 and n=10^15` my code is running for 2.15-2.20 seconds. So i think a little optimization can reduce its running time to less than 2 seconds. Please help.

Comment: Okay, I think I can speed it up a bit. I'd be surprised if it's really necessary, but well, why not, let me try. One question, you use signed integers, and print out the result with negative numbers, if it so happens, but the problem asks for the result modulo 10^9+7, which usually means the remainders with `0 <= r < 10^9+7`. Are you sure that using negative numbers is correct, and if so, which numbers in the result should be negative?

Comment: Can't we add `10^9+7` in the result if it is negative?

Comment: @user1437473 if you are not required to have some entries negative (and probably having negative entries would lead to being judged as a wrong answer, but since you used and produced negative numbers, I'd thought I'd better make sure), an easy speedup is (using `unsigned long long` and) only doing one `%` operation per entry of the product, the sum of four products of numbers (of absolute value) `< 10^9+7` doesn't overflow `(unsigned) long long`.

Answer (score 2):

[Commenters have shown that this answer is incomplete.  The answer is retained here for reference, but wants no more upvotes.  Would the commenters add more complete answers, at their discretion?]

Yes.  An excellent way to do exactly what you want is known.  You must *diagonalize* the matrix.

Diagonalization will require some programming.  The theory is explained [here,](http://derivations.org/) in sect. 14.6.
Fortunately, existing matrix-algebra libraries like LAPACK already include diagonalization routines.

@Haile correctly and interestingly observes that not all matrices are diagonalizable, that there exist degenerate cases.  I do not have much practical experience with such cases.  There is the Schur decomposition (see sect. 14.10 of the previously linked source), but I have normally seen Schur used only to make theoretical points, not to do practical calculations.  Still, I believe that Schur would work.  It would take a lot of effort to implement it, I suspect, but it would work, even in the case of the strictly nondiagonalizable matrix.

Comment: Yes, matrix decomposition into 2 parts would solve. 1 diagonal matrix and 1 anti-diagonal

Comment: What if the matrix is not diagonalizable?

Comment: @Haile:  I have edited the answer to recognize your useful comment.  Thanks.

Comment: I pointed that out because unluckily the matrix in the question is not diagonalizable. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+{{2%2C++1%2C+-2%2C+-1}%2C{+1+%2C+0+%2C+0+%2C+0}+%2C{+0+%2C+1+%2C+0+%2C+0+}%2C+++{0+%2C+0+%2C+1%2C++0+}}).

Comment: what to do now, when matrix is not diagonalizable?

Comment: That doesn't work here except for some very rare fortunate cases (definitely not in the given). The OP wants to calculate the power of the matrix modulo some number. Unless the matrix has only integer eigenvalues, calculating the power of the eigenvalues with enough precision to get the correct modulus is infeasible. Furthermore, for eignevalues whose absolute value is not 1, the power would underflow to 0 resp. overflow to ±Infinity with normal `double`s and such a big exponent.

Comment: @Haile:  I think that you can give a better answer than I have given.  Would you post yours as a separate answer, then notify me here so that I can look at it and, presumably, upvote it?

Comment: @thb I think exponentiation could be made faster by decomposing the matrix in its Jordan Normal Form. However, as Daniel Fischer correctly points out, there are precision issues. The matrix given in the question has irrational eigenvalues. Its Jordan decomposition (see it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+normal+form{{2%2C++1%2C+-2%2C+-1}%2C{+1+%2C+0+%2C+0+%2C+0}+%2C{+0+%2C+1+%2C+0+%2C+0+}%2C+++{0+%2C+0+%2C+1%2C++0+}})) would be made of three 4x4 matrix full of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the multiple test cases to reduce the total computation.

Note that every time you call power you are recomputing all the powers of 2 of your original matrix.  So for a number like 10^15 (roughly 2^50) you will end up squaring a matrix 50 times, and also calculating a multiply for each nonzero bit in the number (perhaps 25 times).

If you simply precompute the 50 powers of 2, then each test case would only require on average 25 multiplications instead of 75.

You can take this idea a little further and use a different base for your exponentiation.  This would result in more precomputation, but fewer final matrix multiplications for each test value.

For example, instead of precomputing M^2, M^4, M^8, M^16 you could precompute [M^1,M^2,M^3],[M^4,M^8,M^12],[M^16,M^32,M^48] and so M^51 would be (M^3)*(M^48) instead of M*M^2*M^16*M^32

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an idea about exponentiating matrices faster, but about speeding up the entire program.

If you are asked to perform 10^4 exponentiations, this doesn't mean they should be done independently. You can sort requests and reuse previous result for each next computation.

Also you can store intermediate results from previous computations.